# WIF exception on Win2003 R2 using Azure ACS and Asp.Net 3.5

Tags: asp.net, .net-3.5, azure, iis-6, wif

We are using Azure ACS together with WIF on a Win2003 R2 server, running Asp.Net 3.5 and receive the following exception once Azure ACS redirects back to our site:

```
Exception information: 
    Exception type: CryptographicException
    Exception message: The system cannot find the file specified.

at System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData.Protect(Byte[] userData, Byte[] optionalEntropy, DataProtectionScope scope) 
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.ProtectedDataCookieTransform.Encode(Byte[] value)
```

From research it seems the AppPool Identity we are running the website under in IIS 6, might not have access to the relevant cryptographic keys, however we have not found a workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The resolution turned out to be as per another post, we had to create a simple Windows Service which runs under the same account as our App Pool on Windows 2003 R2.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you use the SSL certificate used for the site to encrypt the session cookie, and grant access to the private key for that certificate for the user that IIS App Pool runs under.

You can achieve the former in the following way:

First, in your Application Start event, hook up the onServiceConfigurationCreated event:

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Code that runs on application startup
    FederatedAuthentication.ServiceConfigurationCreated += OnServiceConfigurationCreated;

}
```

Then use the following implementation:

```
void OnServiceConfigurationCreated(object sender, ServiceConfigurationCreatedEventArgs e)
{
    //
    // Use the <serviceCertificate> to protect the cookies that are
    // sent to the client.
    //
    if (e.ServiceConfiguration.ServiceCertificate != null)
    {
        List<CookieTransform> sessionTransforms =
            new List<CookieTransform>(new CookieTransform[] {
                new DeflateCookieTransform(), 
                new RsaEncryptionCookieTransform(e.ServiceConfiguration.ServiceCertificate),
                new RsaSignatureCookieTransform(e.ServiceConfiguration.ServiceCertificate)  });
        SessionSecurityTokenHandler sessionHandler = 
            new SessionSecurityTokenHandler(sessionTransforms.AsReadOnly());
        e.ServiceConfiguration.SecurityTokenHandlers.AddOrReplace(sessionHandler);
    }
```

You will need to add that certificate in the Certificates section within microsoft.identityModel section:

> ```
>   <serviceCertificate>
>     <certificateReference x509FindType="FindByThumbprint" findValue="[cert_thumbprint]" />
>   </serviceCertificate>
> ```

And finally to grant the access to the private key for that certificate, to the user that the App Pool runs under, use:

> winhttpcertcfg -g -a "AppPool Account" -c LOCAL_MACHINE\My -s 
>   www.mysite.com

Where, **winhttpcertcfg** is a tool to download from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=19801). **LOCAL_MACHINE\My** the name of Certificate Store, the SSL Cert is locatted. "**www.mysite.com**" is the Subject (CN) name for the SSL Certificate.

I think that this will solve your issue. If not, come back here with the result.

Comment: Attempted the above but while debugging could not break-point into OnServiceConfigurationCreated. The same code runs on another Win2003 R2 server without issue, although that server has Visual Studio 2010 and was used to generate the STS references for the web project.


In event log found:


Exception information: 
    Exception type: SecurityTokenExpiredException 
    Exception message: ID4148: The Saml2SecurityToken is rejected because the SAML2:Assertion's NotOnOrAfter condition is not satisfied.
NotOnOrAfter: '2/05/2012 4:56:45 AM'
Current time: '2/05/2012 5:28:47 AM'